# When handling in NgRX Effect, the effect won't work anymore

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

For the life of me, I can't figure out why once and error is thrown and intercepted, the effect will not work anymore

```
  @Effect()
  register$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(RegisterAction),
      map(action => action.registrationInfo),
      mergeMap(registrationInfo => {
        return this.authService.createUser(registrationInfo.email, registrationInfo.password,
          registrationInfo.lastname, registrationInfo.firstname);
      }),
      map(credentialInfo => ProfileInitAction({credentialInfo})),
      catchError(error => [ProfileInitErrorAction(error)]),
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know why? Because this is the normal workflow in RXJS. So an observable emits values at different times. When an error occurs, then the observable chain (or pipe or subscription, or what you want) breaks. You have a service call. This service call can fail, right? But you do this service call in a child observable chain. So you can handle the error in this child's observable chain, and this will not break your main observable chain. In one word, do the catchError in the mergeMap.

For example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MoviesService } from './movies.service';

@Injectable()
export class MovieEffects {

  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
    mergeMap(() => this.moviesService.getAll() //< --- starting point of the child observable chain
      .pipe(
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY) // <--- this is runs in the child observable chain
      ))
    ) // <--- end of the child observable chain
  ); // <--- end of the main observable chain

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private moviesService: MoviesService
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding caught$ in the catchError seems to fix this.

```
  register$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(RegisterAction),
      map(action => action.registrationInfo),
      mergeMap(registrationInfo => {
        return this.authService.createUser(registrationInfo.email, registrationInfo.password,
          registrationInfo.lastname, registrationInfo.firstname);
      }),
      map(credentialInfo => ProfileInitAction({credentialInfo})),
      catchError((err, caught$) => {
        notify(this.translate.instant('pages.auth.register.notify.error' + ': ' + err['message']), 'error');
        return caught$;
      }),
    );
  });
```